# Need help making a plugin function

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a plugin to collapse breadcrumb elements into a dropdown when the page size is resized.

I can hide the items on resizing no problem.

I can only seem to add back a single item before the script stops working.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have a feeling this is the issue:

```
 var $t = $itemsTextArray[$itemsTextArray.length - 1];

 var $c = "<li class='breadcrumb-item'><a href='#'>" + $t + "</a></li>"; 

 $this.find('.breadcrumb-item:nth-child(2)').after($c);

 $widthOfLastItemMoved = $this.find('.breadcrumb-item:nth-child(3)').text();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chrischilcoat/xfn1rwue/

Comment: After you add the first item back into the breadcrumb, $w is no longer returning as greater than $widthOfLastItemMoved.

Comment: Also $widthOfLastItemMoved is incorrectly using the .text() method in makeBreadCrumb()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the idea of this extension. That being said, there are quite a few issues in this script. I can explain why you are no longer meeting the conditions to trigger makeBreadCrumb(), but even when that is fixed there is still more that is not going to work correctly with your script. Those are for different questions however.

Inside makeBreadCrumb() change:

```
$widthOfLastItemMoved = $this.find('.breadcrumb-item:nth-child(3)').text();
```

To:

```
$widthOfLastItemMoved = $this.find('.breadcrumb-item:nth-child(3)').width();
```

Then inside of update() change:

```
if ($itemsMoved > 0) {
```

to

```
if ($itemsMoved >= 0) {
```

This should get you back into makeBreadCrumb(), but again there are other issues that need to be addressed. Those are different questions.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give that a try. 

I know this script is sucky but its mostly a prototype that I will hand off to a real front end developer to build in react.